# yii2 SluggableBehavior not transform cyrillic to latin

Tags: yii2, behavior

I am using

> yii\behaviors\SluggableBehavior

In order to transform cyrillic title to converted `alias` in lattin.
It works nice at my local but When I uploaded the same code into server It doesnt work. It ignores cyrillic chars. It seems problem is not in code because It works nice at local server ( Maybe I need to install some extension for it ?

thanks

Comment: Check `intl` version on the server.

Comment: This extension wasn't installed at my server. I have just installed it and as a result It works nice now )

Bizley, THANKS a lot !!! You did my day !!!